# PHP Mail xlsx-file created with PHPExcel as attachment

Tags: php, phpexcel, email-attachments

So I'm trying to generate and save an Excel-file to the server. This works flawlessly with PHPExcel. The next step is to read the file, e-mail it as an attachment and then delete it.

For some reason, PHP does not recognize xlsx as a proper file:

```
/* excel is generated before here */
$filename = "/results/excel/export-" . $today . ".xlsx";
$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($exc);
$writer->save($filename);
/* so far so good; the file is created and exists on the server */

$to = "someone@domain.com";
$sendermail = "no-reply@domain.com";
$from = "Sender <" . $sendermail . ">";
$subject = "Email with attachment";
$message = "Here you go";
$file = $filename;

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers = "From: $from";
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"        {$mime_boundary}\""; 

$message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";

if(is_file($file)) {
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    $fp = @fopen($file, "rb");
    $data = @fread($fp, filesize($file));
    @fclose($fp);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . basename($file). ";\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
    $returnpath = "-f" . $sendermail;

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
} else {
    echo("This is not a file: " . $file);
}
```

Which always gives me "This is not a file...". How do I read the XLSX-file?

Comment: check the write permission for php user against the folder where you are saveing the excel file or the /tmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out what it was. $filename was actually a direct (http://...) link to the file, not a relative link. Changed it to be relative and it worked :).

Answer (score 1):

here's a tip to prompt the excel and also send the file as an attachment without saving the file on server:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter     ($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');                                                                                                           
$objWriter->save('php://output');

$data = ob_get_contents();

$sendmail=new ExcelMail($data); //this is your mail class; if you use zend mail use addattachement($data); and Zend_Mime
```

Answer (score 0):

The outputted message means `is_file()` is failing . This  can happen for a number of reasons, but as far as I know not because the file format. As such, I would recommend looking into the following things:

1. Is the file actually there? You say you have the file saved, but you have to make sure it actually is.
2. Is the file path the xslx file is using correct?
3. Is the file path to the xslx file to the actual xml file and not to a symlink to it?
4. Are the permissions of the xslx file set so that the php script is allowed to acces them?

I believe it has to be one of those problems...

Comment: 1. The file is there. If I c/p the path it echoes and point the browser to it, I can download it and open it locally. 2. So yes, that filepath is correct. 3. I'm not sure what you mean :D 4. What should the permissions be? And how do I set the permissions to whatever they should be when saving? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I found out what it was. `$filename` was actually a direct (`http://...`) link to the file, not a relative link. Changed it to be relative and it worked :).